# Ардуино не отвечает на запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial

сейчас я делаю проект и возникла необходимость управления Arduino с помощью Python. На простом коде все работает замечательно, но с усложнение кода возникает баг при котором я отправляю данные на ардуинку, но они не приходят на нее, и приходится использовать на месте `ser.write(b'g') ser.readline().decode("ascii")`, следующую конструкцию `for _ in range(2): ser.write(b'g') ser.readline().decode("ascii")`. Далее привожу код

```
import serial
from serial.tools import list_ports
h = []

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 10)

def play():
    ser.write(b'g')
    a = ser.readline().decode("ascii")
    print(a)

def run(f):
    while True:
        print("Введите в какой USB порт вставлена плата Ардуино (обычно он единственный)")
        print("Порт     Описание")
        print("------------------------------------------")
        for port in list_ports.comports():
            print(port.device, ' : ', port.description)
        usbport = input()
        try:            
            play()

            
            f.write('1\n')
            f.write(usbport)

        except:
            print("Ошибка подключения к порту, попытайтесь снова либо выберите другой порт")
            print(" ")

def ready(f, onoff):
    try:            
        play()
            
    except:
        print('Ошибка порта, выберите другой порт')
        f.truncate(0)
        f.seel(0)
        run(f)


try:
    with open('ardport.txt', 'r+') as f:
        onoff = f.readlines()
        if onoff[0][0] != '1':
            run(f)
        else:
            ready(f, onoff)
            
except:
    with open('ardport.txt', 'w+') as f:
        run(f)
```

Весь код исправно работает, и функция `ser.write(b'')` исправно срабатывает, но ардуинка молчит и не реагирует

Далее код ардуинки, и как я уже упомянул если использовать `ser.write()`внутри цикла `for _ in range(2)` то она сработает два раза правильно и все работает

```
#define led1 5
#define led2 6

byte a = 0;
byte d = 5;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }



void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()>0){  
    Serial.println("Answer == 1");     
    if(Serial.read() == 'g'){
       for (byte i = 0; i<255; i++){
         analogWrite(led1, i);
         delay(d);};
         
       digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       delay(5000);
       
        
  
     while(a<3){
        for (byte i = 0; i<255; i++){
          analogWrite(led2, i);
          delay(d);};
          
        for (byte i = 255; i>0; i--){
          analogWrite(led2, i);
          delay(d);};
          
        digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
        a++;
        delay(500);};

        digitalWrite(led1, LOW); 
   };
  };
  
}
```

Comment: А если добавить`ser.flush()` после `ser.write`?

Comment: У меня все работает(пробовал под линуксом на Arduino Uno ). Из изменений только добавил `a = 0` после `void loop() {`